# How to set default working folder in Rstudio for new session?

Tags: r

I face the problem with changing of working directory. 
Here are my steps to reproduce it:

1. Start R session (The working directory matches the one set in the settings)
2. Change current working directory and start coding
3. Start one more new Session (The working directory for the second session becomes the one used in the previous session but not the one set in the settings)

This is serious problem if i work with folders which contain many files as new session just fails to start

Comment: Using the Projects functionality within RStudio would somewhat alleviate this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following at the beginning of each script:

```
# set the R scripts working directory
library(rstudioapi)
current_path <- getActiveDocumentContext()$path
if (getwd() != current_path){
  setwd(dirname(current_path ))
}
```

This piece of code will define the working directory as the location of the script, it's really useful when working with multiple scripts that has lots of dependencies and they fail due to wrong working directory

**EDIT**

After understanding better the desired behaviour from the comments, you should wrap you code in a project hierarchy and set the the default working directory of the project to the desired one.

*The code I added above is suitable for the case you want your scripts to run regardless of the session working directory*

Comment: This code is really helpful but in my case i can't use it as new sessions starts with working directory; so i'm able to change it only after it loads...

Comment: @ElvinFox Im not sure I understand your comment; when you will run a script with this piece of code at the beginning it will change the directory to where the script is regardless of the starting session working directory

Comment: I can't run any additional script(current session has working script) until i start new session which automatically fails due to lots of files in wd

Comment: As Dfjinnfoy said, you should use Rstudio Projects, with a wd defaulting to the Project home.

Comment: now I understand what was your issue, I've edited the answer to state what @djfinnoy said so it won't mislead users who read the answer